# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a strange case,the website works fine in local but in server i get:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

after extract log i get the error :

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly ' Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

when check the uploaded file it's exactly same version 
[image]

Comment: Delete `bin` folder locally and try to run locally again - can you replicate the issue? Have you recently upgraded this package and an old reference still exist?

Comment: i think it upgraded automatic when add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package, it works fine local with IIS express, but get me an error in server :(

Comment: @Ignas I got the same issue, which works in local visual studio debug mode, while not working in server.
I am trying to replicate the issue in a brand new project.
I can replicate the issue in my own project. It's about upgrade 3 packages.
 
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" /> // original: "1.1.1"`

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />// original: "1.1.2"`

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
// original: "1.1.1"`

Comment: I checked the IIS folder and it's related to the version issue. But I don't know why the version using the old one instead of new. (I setup CI on my own, which automatically publish and deploy.)
I did a naive fix but it works. I simply clean solution and rebuild. then copy and paste all dll with `Microsoft` prefix inside the debug folder, and simply stop and start the IIS.

Comment: I uninstalled the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug and then I had to delete the bin folder. After that, it worked for me.